# PHP redirect - (SNI) misdirected request the client needs a new connection - host does not match the server name indication

Tags: php, ios, redirect, sni

I am redirecting clients to another domain - after receiving a paypal payment.
I am using this PHP code :

```
<?php
header("Location: https://www.domain_example_2.com");
?>
```

It seems to work fine on most devices.
But a few people on iPhones have reported this error:

"**misdirected request the client needs a new connection for this request as the requested host does not match the server name indication (SNI) in use for this connection**"

The domain receiving the paypal transaction confirmation PDT is 
**www.domain_example_1.com** 
it takes the details then sends the user to another domain 
**www.domain_example_2.com**
to log in.

It works fine on other devices.

The domains are hosted on godaddy both domains under the same multi SANS.

---

**1) what is causing this error?**

**2) what is the easiest solution?**

---

I have read a few ideas about it being the multi SANS as a problem and to get a separate certificate for the domain. To also having settings changed on godaddy's side.

If it is the PHP redirect - is there some other method that will not trigger this error?

I want to use the one domain to handle the PDT transaction - and I expect to be sending customer to multiple other domains after transactions.

I do not want to have multiple paypal accounts - as paypal only allows for one PDT URL.

I do not think this error has anything to do with paypal.
But is does seem to effect only iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I also read some questions and as the problems seems to occur only when several conditions are met it's not possible to say which one is responsible. But I would say

> 1) what is causing this error?

connection persistence of your last request before the Paypal

> 2) what is the easiest solution?

Don't persist that connection. If you know which page is always called before proceeding to Paypal, you could add a header asking to close the connection like :

```
header("Connection: Close");
```

Or try sending a JavaScript with code forcing the browser to redirect instead of a 302 Location. This JavaScript could be sent only when the User-Agent is an iPhone, and keep the normal 302 Location for others. Note I didn't try, I would rather close the connection than this.

Comment: downvoters : please explain what's wrong in my answer if you know it.